# CDI/Weld: book or resource recommendation

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld

Is there an existing, or upcoming book on CDI/Weld that you can recommend?

I'm looking for something that's similar in scope and quality to [Seam in Action](http://www.manning.com/dallen/), which was a great reference for Seam, but now seems a little dated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing I can confirm that there is nothing like this (though badly needed). Dan Allen, the Author of "Seam in Action" was interviewed for the German JavaMagazin in 2010 and stated that he has no direct plans for a sequel.

Your best options so far:

Online:

- [weld@seamframework.org](http://www.seamframework.org/Weld)
- [Context and Dependency Injection Advocacy](https://sites.google.com/site/cdipojo/get-started)

Offline:

- "Enterprise  JavaBeans 3.1" / Andrew Rubinger & Bill Burke / O'Reilly (At least a chapter about CDI, but far away from the information density of Dan Allen's SIA)

Comment: The lack of a good reference is actually preventing me from using this in projects. :-(

Comment: Definitely a decision worth rethinking. True: There are not too many good books covering CDI out there. False: There's no reference available. It's just online - but it's very very much worth a try :-)

Answer (score 5):

[That collection](http://jaxenter.com/java-tech-journal-issue-16-cdi-41534.html) of articles has recently been released. It's for free, but you have to register - that's why I did not check it out yet ;-) But the authors, Mark Struberg and Pete Muir are true CDI experts. Certainly worth to have a look at.

Comment: Unfortunately the Java Tech Magazine is not published anymore and old issues are gone.

Comment: Amazing how time flies by, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a German book upcoming, that looks quite promising: http://www.amazon.de/CDI-Mit-Java-voll-durchstarten/dp/3868020713.