# Recommendation on where I should start reading about CDI (Weld)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I found this 
[CDI/Weld: book or resource recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293941/cdi-weld-book-or-resource-recommendation), and yes it is the same question but it is "old" now so I wonder if it has come any updates on this question?

I am in the process of learning Java EE 6 so I am looking for books/tutorials that explains it from the basic. I found this:

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/pdf/weld-reference.pdf
&
http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/tck/reference/1.0.4.SP1/pdf/jsr299-tck-reference-guide.pdf

I don't know which of them I should read (probably both, but I need to start somewhere. Or are there other places I should start instead?

Answer (score 7):

The following articles may not be very new but I think they are useful if you want to learn about CDI:

1. [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6: Part I](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1373391/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-1)
2. [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6: Part II](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1379813/Dependency-injection-in-Java-EE-part-2)
3. [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6: Part III](http://www.theserverside.com/news/2240016831/Part-3-of-dependency-injection-in-Java-EE-6)
4. [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6: Part IV](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Conversations-Part-4)
5. [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6: Part V](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-5)
6. [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6: Part VI](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-6)

Answer (score 3):

Start with the Weld tutorial, is way easier to read and targets the principles of CDI in a much easier way than the TCK reference (even though the reference is a good for quick references, just as the name suggests).

Unfortunately, there are still (10/2011) no books available. *"Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1" / Andrew Rubinger & Bill Burke / O'Reilly* is still the best deal should you prefer offline reading. :-(